# Playwright.js element not found error handling

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm converting a bunch of tests from Selenium + Jest to Playwright + Jest, and one of the differences is that for element lookups, `await page.$(".whatever")` doesn't reject if it doesn't find the element.

I'm doing a lot of element lookups as we've built out Page Object Models for a lot of components.

My question is, do I need to manually add some error handling, or am I missing something here? Jest will tell me which test fails but there's no stack trace so it can be hard to track down what went wrong. Also, is this a good way to do it?

```js
// some-test.js
it("should display the event title", async () => {
  let eventTitle = await this.bookingPage.getEventTitle();
  expect(await eventTitle.textContent()).toBe("Some special event");
});
```

```js
// Page Object Model

class BookingPage extends PageObjectModel {
  async getEventTitle() {
    const selector = "h2.title .content";
    const result = await page.$(selector);
    if (!result) throw new Error(`Could not find selector: "${selector}"`);
    return result;
  }
}
```

If it is a good approach it seems like a pain to have to do for all lookups. Would it be a good idea to wrap `page.$` in another function that just does it for me? It would be a bad idea to mutate `page.$` itself right? So maybe create a wrapper method that does the error handling and it and then calls `page.$`?

So I could do something like this:

```js
class PageObjectModel {
  async $(selector) {
    const result = await page.$(selector);
    if (!result) throw new Error(`Could not find selector: "${selector}"`);
    return result;
  }
}
```

```js
class BookingPage extends PageObjectModel {
  async getEventTitle() {
    return this.$("h2.title .content");
  }
}
```

Which is kinda nice but then for some reason the stack trace only links to `some-test.js` and `PageObjectModel.js`, and not to `BookingPage.js`.

I feel like I'm not missing something about JS error handling in general? ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so in the end I found that you can use [page.waitForSelector](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page?_highlight=waitforsel#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) which will also return the element if it's found and will reject with a `TimeoutError` if it's not found, which is what I wanted.

For some reason the stack-trace still only links to `some-test.js` and `PageObjectModel.js` however if I catch and re-throw it in `BookingPage.js` then it does add that to the stack trace.

I don't actually need to throw it, I just need to log it out. So this is the solution I'm going with:

```js
// some-test.js - ** unchanged **
it("should display the event title", async () => {
  let eventTitle = await this.bookingPage.getEventTitle();
  expect(await eventTitle.textContent()).toBe("Some special event");
});
```

```js
class PageObjectModel {
  async $(selector) {
    return page.waitForSelector(selector);
  }
}
```

```js
class BookingPage extends PageObjectModel {
  async getEventTitle() {
    return await this.$("h2.title .content").catch(console.error);
  }
}
```

It's a bit weird as according to [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/) `await return` is redundant outside of try/catch, but I guess because I'm using `.catch` it's functionally the same as try catch?

Anyway, this gives me the stack trace that I want.